# Is Google Player Game Console still checking TrustManager implementation on Android apk?

Tags: android-security, trustmanager

As of June 6th 2016, is this check for alert still in effect for Google Player?
 https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016

On June 6th, we submitted several testing app which are supposed to generate the security warning message in alpha/beta channel of testing as well as tested pushing APK to production.

We are not able to reproduce any alert in Google Player Developer Console.

Is this policy has been lifted for any reason or is it because any thing else that I can not reproduce the warning? Thus we can only think our APK has no such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the policy hasn't been changed. It's possible that you aren't getting alerts because the code is too complicated for the scanner to detect.